# error with self mutating enum function

Tags: swift, enums, malloc

I seem to be getting an error when I replace an enum with a larger instance of the enum. It runs okay as a swift playground but when I run it on an iOS device I get an `malloc` error:

```
enum E {
  case small
  case big(foo:[Int])
  mutating func swap(with e:E) {
    self = e //malloc: *** error for object 0x13805d000: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
  }
}

var i = [Int](1...100000)
var a = E.small
var b = E.big(foo:i)
a.swap(with:b)
```

Why would the line `self = e` through a runtime error?

Comment: Maybe the device doesn't have enough available RAM to hold the 100k elements array and it's copies that are made while passing it around

Comment: This works fine and would likely be a memory error.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't want to print between ```[Int](1...66266)``` and ```[Int](1...66267)```